# Drag down formula advancing one row and one column

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to drag down formulas while advancing a column and a row each time I drag down.

I want to drag down the formula in N2 in such a way that the formula in N3 becomes

```
=1-(E3/C3)
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I have forgotten what the requirement was (Sheets example is no longer publicly viewable) but assuming N2 is to calculate `1-(D2/B2)` (N4: `1-(F4/D4)` etc up to N11 at most) then perhaps:

```
=1-indirect(char(column()+52+row())&row())/indirect(char(column()+50+row())&row())
```

in N2 and copied down to suit.

In N3 the effect would be of:

```
=1-(E3/C3)
```

Comment: That does not seem to work but the general idea seems worth exploring (I did not know how to convert numbers to letters in sheets).